# Pulling info by greater than statement in lists (Python)

Tags: python

I used the csv module to create lists from a data file. It looks something like this now:

```
['unitig_5\t.\tregion\t401\t500\t0.00\t+\t.\tcov2=3.000', '0.000;gaps=0',
    '0;cov=3', '3', '3;cQv=20', '20', '20;del=0;ins=0;sub=0']

['unitig_5\t.\tregion\t2201\t2300\t0.00\t+\t.\tcov2=10.860',
    '1.217;gaps=0', '0;cov=8', '11', '13;cQv=20', '20', '20;del=0;ins=0;sub=0']
```

I need to pull lists and put them into a new file if `cov2=` (part of the first column above) is equal to some number greater than some specified integer (say 140), so then in that case the two lists above wouldn't be accepted.

How would I set it up to check which lists meet this qualification and put those lists to a new file?

Comment: Is `cov2=...` always at the end of the first string?

Comment: Yes it is, the end of each first string

Answer (score 0):

You can use `regex` :

```
>>> l=['unitig_5\t.\tregion\t401\t500\t0.00\t+\t.\tcov2=3.000', '0.000;gaps=0',
...     '0;cov=3', '3', '3;cQv=20', '20', '20;del=0;ins=0;sub=0']

>>> import re
>>> float(re.search(r'cov2=([\d.]+)',l[0]).group(1))
3.0
```

The pattern `r'cov2=([\d.]+)'` will match and combination of digits (`\d`) and dot with length 1 or more. then you can convert the result to float and compare :

```
>>> var=float(re.search(r'cov2=([\d.]+)',l[0]).group(1))
>>> var>140
False
```

Also as its possible that your regex doesn't match the pattern you can use a `try-except` to handle the exception :

```
try :

    var=float(re.search(r'cov2=([\d.]+)',l[0]).group(1))
    print var>140

except AttributeError:
    #print 'the_error_message'
```

Answer (score 0):

I would first split the first string by tabs "\t", which seems to separate the fields.
Then, if cov2 is always the last fild, further parsing would be easy (cut of "cov2=", then convert the remainder to float and compare.

If not necessarily the last field, a simple search for the start should be sufficient.
Of course, complexity could be increased indefinitively if error-checking or a more tolerant search is required.

Answer (score 0):

```
lst = [ ['unitig_5\t.\tregion\t401\t500\t0.00\t+\t.\tcov2=3.000', '0.000;gaps=0',
    '0;cov=3', '3', '3;cQv=20', '20', '20;del=0;ins=0;sub=0'],
        ['unitig_5\t.\tregion\t2201\t2300\t0.00\t+\t.\tcov2=10.860',
    '1.217;gaps=0', '0;cov=8', '11', '13;cQv=20', '20', '20;del=0;ins=0;sub=0'], ]

filtered_list = [ l for l in lst if re.match('.*cov2=([\d.]+$'), l) ]
```

Answer (score 0):

You could extract the float value using rsplit if all the first elements contain the substring:

```
for row in list_of_rows:
    if float(row[0].rsplit("=",1)[1]) > 140:
            # write rows
```

If you don't actually need every row you should do it when you first read the file writing as you go.

```
with open("input.csv") as f, open("output.csv", "w") as out:
    r = csv.reader(f)
    wr = csv.writer(out)
    for row in r:
        if float(row[0].rsplit("=", 1)[1]) > 140:
            wr.writerows(row)
```

Comment: When I try this I get a list index out of range error for the if statement

Comment: print the row before the if and show me what it looks like

Comment: It looks the same as what I put in the original post. It has the items in the list like this: ['unitig_19\t.\tregion\t13821\t13853\t0.00\t+\t.\tcov2=1.818', '0.386;gaps=0', '0;cov=1', '2', '2;cQv=20', '20', '20;del=0;ins=0;sub=0']

Comment: If you print `float(row[0].rsplit("=", 1)[1])` you will see it works on the list above so that cannot be what is happening